# How to stub an uncaughtException listener in node with sinon

Tags: node.js, sinon, stub

i have a custom handler for uncaught exceptions that i want to test. with all the attempts, i have also tried inside a forked child process as well.

this is a contrived example...

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function(err) {
  otherFunction(err.message);
});

it('should catch exceptions', function() {
  stub(otherFunction);

  throw new Error('foo');

  assert.calledWith(otherFunction, 'foo');
});
```

is there something i need to use with my stubbing tool (currently using sinon), or is this entirely the wrong approach?

Answer (score 1):

Any error thrown inside an `it`function should fail that test. You can wrap the throw statement with try{} and in catch block you can write the assert function.

Comment: i had tried something similar, but since i was then catching it, it was no longer an uncaught exception and so never called the handler... this was what led me to trying to use a child process. but after taking a break from it and getting a night's rest, i will play around with it again...